# What is a dynamic SQL query, and when would I want to use one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

What is a dynamic SQL query, and when would I want to use one?  I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: How is this "spam" and "not a real question"? It might not be fleshed out, but it's understandable enough to answer.

Comment: +1 for the abuse of down-votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a few articles:

- [Introduction to Dynamic SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1)
- [Dynamic SQL Beginner's Guide](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438931/Dynamic-SQL-Beginners-Guide.htm)

From *Introduction to Dynamic SQL*:

> *Dynamic SQL* is a term used to mean SQL code that is generated programatically (in part or fully) by your program before it is executed. As a result it is a very flexible and powerful tool. You can use dynamic SQL to accomplish tasks such as adding where clauses to a search based on what fields are filled out on a form or to create tables with varying names.

Comment: Another critical, must-read link if you are going to use dynamic SQL:http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic SQL is SQL generated by the calling program. This can be through an ORM tool, or ad-hoc by concatenating strings. Non-dynamic SQL would be something like a stored procedure, where the SQL to be executed is predefined. Not all DBA's will let you run dynamic SQL against their database due to security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic SQL query is one that is built as the program is running as opposed to a query that is already (hard-) coded at compile time.

The program in question might be running either on the client or application server (debatable if you'd still call it 'dynamic') or within the database server.