# Find all Tables that contain Column Name; Filter Empties

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been using the SQL found here:
[Find all tables containing column with specified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

to great success. It allows me to find all tables that contain a certain column. My issue is that the database I'm working on seems to have a lot of empty tables (maybe around half of my results are empties). I was wondering if there was a way to modify the code in the link such that empty rows/columns are not presented.Below is the code from the link:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%MyName%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Thank you,

Comment: You could do it using dynamic SQL. Is that an option?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what that is. I did a quick look on Google and the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165020/what-is-dynamic-sql Says that Dynamic SQL can hurt performance or it isn't always necessary... I'm willing to try, but regular SQL might be better?

Comment: @JohnnyBaggadoughnuts dynamic sql is actually pretty good for this kind of thing. Although I'd go with Dan's answer using sys.partitions.

Comment: Is performance a concern?  This doesn't seem like you should be running all the time - more like a maintenance task?

Comment: I don't think performance is much of a concern. I'd only run this when I was looking to find something. It's more like maintenance, yes.

Comment: The whole idea behind dynamic sql is that you are creating your query initially as a string of text and then executing that string. I will see if I can put something together,. I didn't know about sys.partitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this may work without huge effort:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
            ,p.rows
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
on t.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%p%'
            AND p.rows > 0
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Just note that `sys.partitions` isn't guaranteed to be accurate about row counts; `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` may be better (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55124/how-accurate-is-the-sys-partition-rows-column).  This might give you a better count but may have more locking issues if you're using AlwaysOn:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
            ,ips.record_count
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), t.object_id, null, null, 'DETAILED') ips
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%p%'           
            AND ips.record_count > 0
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

If you really need 100% reliability on this, you'd have actually do a `COUNT(*)` on each table (using Dynamic SQL) you want to check, but this is probably good enough.

Comment: I'd say sys.partitions is more than accurate enough for this kind of check (zero vs. non-zero).

Comment: Very likely yes, but if you're outputing a row count it may be helpful to have it be more accurate than less

Comment: Thanks Dan, this should work well. There's a column for rows now, which is necessary, but I can export to CSV and filter that out with Excel or something. I'll only be running this every few weeks or months so it's not a huge cocnern. Thanks again,

Comment: If you don't need that column outputted, you can just comment it out from the select or remvoe it entirely (e.g. remove `p.rows` or `ips.record_count`).  If this answers your question, consider marking the question as answered (the check box below the vote selector) for future readers.